# Trouble using WS02 DSS to implement oData Service

Tags: wso2, odata, wso2-data-services-server

I'm trying to use WSO2 Data Services Server to implement oData against a Northwinds Sql Server DB.  I can successfully create a datasource but never see a checkbox to enable oData.  Has anyone had any luck implementing oData services using DSS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the oData sample provided by WSO2 data service server? [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/OData+Sample).

Also refer [2](http://wso2howto.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-create-odata-services-with-wso2.html) on how to create odata services using wso2 dss.